# How to generate Bonsai Tree, Octomap

Tags: ros, kinect, octomap, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have a colored octomap of my office.

I know that can generate .bt and .ot files using graph2tree tool. I also learned that using the graphs provided within the datasets [here](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/datasets/octomap/index_en.php?lang=en), one can generate necessary tree(.ot file) to use in octovis.

Then, how do I create a graph with my kinect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43192/how-to-generate-bonsai-tree,-octomap/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The http://ros.org/wiki/octomap_server package builds an octree from pointcloud data.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-09-06**:
Thanks for the reply and sorry for the dummy question. I am not used to the jargon yet. Also, I believe that differences in several versions of octomap make older documents obsolete. I have been lost a lot of times.